# How to display the passed variable if it passed in text box

Tags: php, laravel

I have a 3 pages: A, B, and C. I have written a code in Laravel to pass value from A to B from database dude. In which title of A is passed when user clicked the link button in A to B form. But i want to implement the condition where passed variable is displayed in the form of B when user goes through A and display input box when go through page C.

This is the code that links page B from page A:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('Bcontroller@show',['title' => $dude->title]) }}" title="B">B</a>
```

My controller code is:

```
public function show($title){
        return Theme::view("B")->with('title',$title);
}
```

My B page looks like this:

```
<input type="title" name="title" value="{{$title}}" placeholder="title" />
```

My page C html looks like this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('Bcontroller@show') }}" title="C">C</a>
```

I try to use

```
@if (isset($title)){
    <input type="title" name="title" value="{{$title}}" placeholder="title" />

}@else {
    <input type="title" name="title" value="" placeholder="title" />
}
```

I expect to implement the condition where user can see title in form when it goes through page A and blank form when user go through C.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do with this logic but you can do what you are asking like this:

These links will take user to page B.

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('Bcontroller@show',['title' => $dude->title,'page' => 'A']) }}" title="A">A</a>

<a href="{{ URL::action('Bcontroller@show',['title' => $dude->title,'page' => 'C']) }}" title="C">C</a>
```

I added one more parameter in the URL which you will get at your controller function, you can pass this parameter to your view B.

```
public function show($title,$page){
        return Theme::view("B")->with(compact('title','page'));
}
```

Based on this parameter value you can show your input text field or whatever.

```
@if ($page == 'C'){
    <input type="title" name="title" value="{{$title}}" placeholder="title" />

}@else {
    <input type="title" name="title" value="" placeholder="title" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to well understand the problem, but I think you could use the `$_GET['']` attribute to navigate between your pages.

If I didn't get the problem, let me know.

Have fun :)

Comment: Hi Lucas, I want to implement a condition when navigatiing to page B from different pages. 
I have been able to implement passing the title. But, I couldn't make a condition while going through page A display title in form and while going through page B form should be empty

Comment: @jenna and what about transmitting the previous page's name. For example from page B to C, `href="page_c.html?prev=page_b"`. Then in page C just `$prev = $_GET['prev'];`. finally use this condition `if($prev == "page_b"){ ... }`